# Google Chrome debugging mode

Tags: python, windows, selenium, google-chrome, remote-debugging

I'm trying to open Google Chrome with debugging mode on the 9222 port. But when Chrome opens I can see on "chrome://version/" that it used the default profile path but not that I'm giving.

Here is the code:

```
CHROME_EXE_PATH --remote-debugging-port=9222 -user-data-dir=".\\chrome_profile"
```

How can I force it to open chrome with my selected profile?

Comment: A typo? A Google Chrome command line option keyword  prefix  should be *double* Hyphen-Minus (`--user-data-dir` instead of `-user-data-dir`)?

Comment: That was true. I fixed the typo but faced another issue. 

At first, when I run the command I got a message box with the following "google chrome cannot read and write to its data directory"

After I run the command with administrator permissions, in this case, Chrome opens and read the default directory.

Comment: `".\chrome_profile"` is a _relative_ path: a leading period represents the current directory (supposedly `Google` under `"%ProgramFiles%"` or `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%"` or `"%ProgramData%"` - all protected). Read the docs for [Overriding the User Data Directory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md) - all examples show _absolute_ paths…